# Why we want a function to be well-defined?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, equivalence-relations

This questions arised to me when I realized that $\neq$ is not an equivalence relation ($1\neq 1$ is false, and $1\neq 2\neq 1$ is false) and applying the operations leads to contradictions, like $1\neq 2 \implies 1\cdot 0\neq 2\cdot 0$ is false. So, what part of the definition of the functions let us apply it to the equivalence relations without leading us to contradictions? This reminded me that all we do with functions, if it's not *well-defined* it doesn't work. I got the definition of the function from [EQUIVALENCE RELATIONS, WELL-DEFINEDNESS... - ALLAN YASHINSKI](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Eallan/WellDefinedness.pdf) pdf, which is the following.

A function $f$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, is a subset of $X\times Y$ with the following property:
$$
(\forall x\in X)(\exists! y\in Y)[(x,y)\in f]
$$
[...].
This means, for each $x\in X$, there exists a **unique** $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$. Here, $f$ is a set and $(x,y)\in f$ is equivalent to $f(x)=y$.

Why we want to exists a **unique** $y\in Y$ instead that only exists, without uniqueness; i.e., to what call *well-defined*?

I think this might be related of, what leads us to jump from binary relations to functions? And which part of working with functions and equivalence relations breaks without needing to be *well-defined*?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. The binary relation $\ne$ is well-defined on any set but as you have shown it's clearly not an equivalence relation. Why would you then expect it to behave as one?

Comment: *Why we want to exists a* ***unique*** $y\in Y$ *instead that only exists* --- The intention is to formalize (i.e. define within the axiomatic system) a concept that agrees with the ordinary meaning of function ("agrees" in the sense when viewed at the metalogic level), where for each (appropriate) input there is one and only one output. Recall the [vertical line test for functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test) from school mathematics.

Comment: "So, what part of the definition of the functions let us apply it to the equivalence relations without leading us to contradictions?" None.  You *can't* apply functions to equivalent items and expect equivalence to hold. Why on earth do you think you can? Take $A=(-\infty,7]$ and $B=(7,\infty)$. The $a R b$ if $a,b$ are both in the same set is an equivalence relationship.  $f(x)=x+2$ is a function.  Bu $1 \equiv 6$ but $1+2=3 \not R 6+2 = 8$.

Comment: Tipically, a *function* is a "mechanism" that takes a value as *input* and produces a value as *output*. If not well-defined, we cannot use it to generate **the** output value.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what part of the definition of the functions let us apply it to the equivalence relations without leading us to contradictions?

What on earth do you mean?  You *can't* apply functions to equivalence relations.

Take the equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$, $a$ is equivalent to $b$ if $a-b$ is an integer.  So $1.25 \cong 2.25 \cong 37.25$.  And take the function $f(x) = x^2$.  Then $f(1.25) = 1.5625$ and $f(2.25) =5.0625$ but $5.0625-1.5625 = 3.5$ is not an integer so $1.5625\not\cong 6.0625$